# How to add .inc files based on variable for recursive automake

Tags: makefile, compilation, autotools, automake

I have the following folder structure:

```
Top folder
|-- configure.ac
|-- Makefile.am
|-- Folder1
|   `-- Makefile.inc
`-- Folder2
    `-- Makefile.inc
```

Only one child Makefile.inc should be included by Makefile.am, and that should be decided based on a flag passed to ./configure, e.g.:

```
./configure FOLDER_TO_INCLUDE=FOLDER1
```

This is what I have attempted:

configure.ac:

```
FOLDER_TO_INCLUDE=$(FOLDER_TO_INCLUDE)
AC_SUBST(FOLDER_TO_INCLUDE)
```

Makefile.am:

```
include $(srcdir)/@FOLDER_TO_INCLUDE@/Makefile.inc
```

However instead of the final Makefile including the child .inc content, it just contains this line:

```
include $(srcdir)/Folder1/Makefile.inc
```

Is there any way around this issue?

Answer (score 0):

As you seem to appreciate, `include` statements are processed by Automake, not by `make`.  What you do not seem to appreciate is that Automake's (and Autoconf's) full effect is delivered in building *the build system*, especially the `configure` script and a `Makefile.in` file corresponding to each `Makefile.am`.  Thus, `include` statements cannot usefully depend on output variables determined by `configure`.

You should be able to use [Automake conditionals](https://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/html_node/Conditionals.html#Conditionals) instead.  That will have pieces in both `configure.ac`:

```
AM_CONDITIONAL([INCLUDE_FOLDER1], [test "$which_folder" = "Folder1"])
```

and in `Makefile.am`:

```
if INCLUDE_FOLDER1
  include $(srcdir)/Folder1/Makefile.inc
endif
```

You will need a separate conditional for each subfolder.  This approach will perform the lexical inclusion when Automake runs, but in such a way that the included contents are effective only when the associated condition is satisfied at `configure` time.

Comment: Thanks @John for the reply. After a while, what I ended up doing is modifying my autogen.sh script such that it creates a new Makefile.inc with a single include line inside. Then in the Makefile.am I just need to include that Makefile and I'm done. Since that Makefile creation happens before calling configure, everything is good and I don't need a conditional for each subfolder.